# postgres- start process under administrator account

Tags: windows, postgresql

Is it possible to start postgres process with a user account that has "administrative" privileges? I am on windows XP.

--Error shown is --- (Not really error, it is a security feature)

```
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromises.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.
```

Current work around is to create normal user and run process under that.  What I am looking at is quick way to start database, do some operations and shut it down as part of build process.

Comment: Is the postgres process started whilest starting windows or do you want to start it independently with the start/stop commands from the startmenu?

Comment: I want to do it as part of build process. (an ant task, specifically)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(years later)

Postgres ships with a control program.  See details in [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pg-ctl.html)

Short answer:

```
pg_ctl start "args"
```